# Get Element By Id ---- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I am try to edit the html through Javascript with gdocument.getElementById but I always come across the error: Uncaught TypeError --- Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Here is my very simple code

```
<html>
    <head>  
        <title>External .js File- Page 3</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <script language="JavaScript">
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Hi!";
        </script>

        <article id="text"></article>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's like trying to drink beer from a glass which isn't filled yet

Comment: you need to wait until the page has loaded, i.e. `window.onload = function() { your code here }`

Comment: `<article>` doesn't exist until HTML 5, but `language` was deprecated in HTML 4 and is [obsolete in HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#attr-script-language). Get rid of the language attribute.

Comment: Thank you guys you were a lot of help! Lol I thought something in my code was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get the element before it exists.

Move the script so it appears after the element.

(Or wrap the code in a function, then [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) that function to an event handler like `load`).

Comment: Is there a way to delay it other than just moving its position?

Comment: Yes, see the third line of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
window.onload = function(){

     document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Hi!";

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You execute the script before the element exists. document.getElementById is looking for 'text' but it's not there yet. You must put your script inside window onload event like so:

```
window.onLoad = function () {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = "Hi";
};
```